# 500 Server Error when sending a request to Twitter API

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm sending the following request to the Twitter API and it is getting the following error:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=feel%2BOR%2Bi%27m%2BOR%2Bi+am%2BOR%2Bim%2BOR%2Bmakes+me%2BOR%2Bmade+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me+feel%2BOR%2Bmy+mood%2BOR%2Bi%27m+so%2BOR%2Bim+so&rpp=99&page=14

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andrew\Downloads\twitterthingv5test.py", line 95, in <module>
    moodParser()
  File "C:\Users\andrew\Downloads\twitterthingv5test.py", line 93, in moodParser
    query()
  File "C:\Users\andrew\Downloads\twitterthingv5test.py", line 37, in query
    main(columns)
  File "C:\Users\andrew\Downloads\twitterthingv5test.py", line 52, in main
    response = urllib2.urlopen(twiturl)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

The code I am using to generate the URL is this:

```
twiturl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + urlinfo + "&rpp=99&page=14"
```

What's going on? Would this be an instance of sending too many requests at once?

Answer (score 0):

It's doing the same for me at the first attempt, so it's probably not a rate limit. Repeatedly shortening the query:

- http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=feel%2BOR%2Bi%27m%2BOR%2Bi+am%2BOR%2Bim%2BOR%2Bmakes+me%2BOR%2Bmade+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me+feel%2BOR%2Bmy+mood%2BOR%2Bi%27m+so%2BOR%2Bim+so&rpp=99&page=14 fails
- http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=feel%2BOR%2Bi%27m%2BOR%2Bi+am%2BOR%2Bim%2BOR%2Bmakes+me%2BOR%2Bmade+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me+feel%2BOR%2Bmy+mood%2BOR%2Bi%27m+so&rpp=99&page=14 fails
- http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=feel%2BOR%2Bi%27m%2BOR%2Bi+am%2BOR%2Bim%2BOR%2Bmakes+me%2BOR%2Bmade+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me+feel%2BOR%2Bmy+mood&rpp=99&page=14 fails
- http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=feel%2BOR%2Bi%27m%2BOR%2Bi+am%2BOR%2Bim%2BOR%2Bmakes+me%2BOR%2Bmade+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me+feel&rpp=99&page=14 succeeds

This is makes me think it's a limit on query length. Adding letters back until it fails again, which is part way through the word `mood`:

- http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=feel%2BOR%2Bi%27m%2BOR%2Bi+am%2BOR%2Bim%2BOR%2Bmakes+me%2BOR%2Bmade+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me+feel%2BOR%2Bmy+m&rpp=99&page=14 succeeds sometimes

Yet, a query string of 260 characters succeeds:

- http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&rpp=99&page=14 succeeds

The [docs say](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) about the `q` parameter:

> A UTF-8, URL-encoded search query of 1,000 characters maximum, including operators. Queries may additionally be limited by complexity.

It's weird that cutting halfway a word counts as additional complexity, but there you go.

Comment: So it does seem to be blocking it based on complexity.